# Magento 1.9.2.4 compatibility issue with Php 7

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, shopping-cart, image-upload, php-7

i am getting 2 problems with Php 7 in Magento 1.9.2.4

[image: Problem 1]

Problem 2 is the wrong calculation of Order Total Amount in checkout.

Please guide how i can implement PHP 7 with Magento 1.9.2.4

Further also please recommend, is it worthy to use PHP 7 with Magento 1.9.2.4??

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1 is not compatible with PHP 7 out of the box.

To make it compatible you need to install the following module: https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

Also in order to ensure your 3rd party modules I recommend you use the following tool : https://github.com/sstalle/php7cc